# Why does transaction fails with already rolled back when user inputs in wrong email

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm authorizing emails in the database but when I input wrong email it throws Transaction cannot be rolled back because it has been finished with state: commit

```
export const signin = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const transaction = await db.sequelize.transaction();
  try {
    const user = await db.User.findOne({ where: { email } }, { transaction });
    await transaction.commit();
    const passBool = Auth.comparePassword(password, user.password);
    if (user && passBool) {
      return res.json({
        success: 1,
        user,
        message: 'signed in'
      });
    }
    res.json({ success: 0, message: 'wrong username or password' });
  } catch (ex) {
    await transaction.rollback();
    res.json({ success: 0, message: 'wrong username or password' });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this, it would fail if i had inserted in wrong request body params

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why rolling back doesn't work in your example, but you can try:

1. A transaction should be passed in the options object of the query:

   ```
   const user = await db.User.findOne({ where: { email }, transaction });
   ```
2. You can try using managed transaction, to avoid manual handling of commit/rollback:

   ```
   export const signin = async (req, res) => {
       const { email, password } = req.body;
       db.sequelize.transaction(async transaction => {
           const user = await db.User.findOne({ where: { email }, transaction });
           const passBool = Auth.comparePassword(password, user.password);
           if (user && passBool) {
               return res.json({
                   success: 1,
                   user,
                   message: 'signed in'
               });
           }
           res.json({ success: 0, message: 'wrong username or password' });
       }).catch(err => {
           res.json({ success: 0, message: 'wrong username or password' });
       });
   };
   ```